# EntityFramework Transaction Scope - not rolling back 1st transaction

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am attempting to create a transaction that encapsulates 4 database table inserts and 2 updates.

I is "mostly" working. By that I mean if I get an error at any one of these 6 db interactions, the prior rollbacks occur...EXCEPT the first one. The first is an insert to a Header table...the subsequent inserts to detail tables and even another header table, etc...all rollback...but if after the rollback you examine the tables, all of them will have no records, except the first one.

```
//Create receipt, ic, printq; update pod, poh
        public List<ActionConfirmation<int>> CreateReceipt(
            IEnumerable<ReceiptDetailPalletListViewModel> viewModelList,
            int intUserId,
            int intFacilityId,
            int intLocationId
        )
        {
            var dbContext = new InventoryMgmtContext();

            //Opening connection
            dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            int intReceiptHdrId = 0;
            int intICHdrId = 0;

            var results = new List<ActionConfirmation<int>>();

            foreach (ReceiptDetailPalletListViewModel viewModel in viewModelList)
            {
                if (viewModel.ReceivedQty > 0)
                {
                    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        //Create Receipt Header
                        ActionConfirmation<int> rcptHdrResult = CreateReceiptHeader(
                            dbContext,
                            intUserId,
                            intFacilityId); <===== This Tran never rolls back. Insert occured.

                        results.Add(rcptHdrResult);

                        if (!rcptHdrResult.WasSuccessful) //Recp Hdr create failed.
                        {
                            CloseFailedTrans(dbContext, transaction);

                            return results;
                        }

                        intReceiptHdrId = rcptHdrResult.Value;

                        //Create new ICHeader
                        ActionConfirmation<int> icHdrResult = CreateICHeader(
                            dbContext,
                            intUserId,
                            intFacilityId,
                            intLocationId,
                            intReceiptHdrId
                        );

                        results.Add(icHdrResult);

                        if (!icHdrResult.WasSuccessful)
                        {
                            CloseFailedTrans(dbContext, transaction);

                            return results;
                        }

                        intICHdrId = icHdrResult.Value;

                        //Create new ICDetail
                        ActionConfirmation<int> icDtlResult = CreateICDetail(
                            dbContext,
                            intICHdrId,
                            viewModel.ItemId,
                            viewModel.PODetailId,
                            viewModel.ReceivedQty,
                            intUserId
                        );

                        results.Add(icDtlResult);

                        if (!icDtlResult.WasSuccessful)
                        {
                            CloseFailedTrans(dbContext, transaction);

                            return results;
                        }

                        //Create new Recpt Detail
                        ActionConfirmation<int> rcptDtlResult = CreateReceiptDetail(
                            dbContext,
                            intReceiptHdrId,
                            viewModel.PODetailId,
                            viewModel.ReceivedQty,
                            intUserId
                        );

                        results.Add(rcptDtlResult);

                        if (!rcptDtlResult.WasSuccessful)
                        {
                            CloseFailedTrans(dbContext, transaction);

                            return results;
                        }

                        //Update PO Detail qty and Header status
                        List<ActionConfirmation<int>> poResults = UpdatePODetail(
                            dbContext,
                            viewModel.PODetailId,
                            viewModel.ReceivedQty,
                            intUserId
                        );

                        foreach (ActionConfirmation<int> poResult in poResults)
                        {
                            results.Add(poResult);

                            if (!poResult.WasSuccessful)
                            {
                                CloseFailedTrans(dbContext, transaction);

                                return results;
                            }
                        }

                        //Create new Print Q
                        ActionConfirmation<int> printqResult = CreatePrintQRecords(
                            dbContext,
                            intICHdrId,
                            intFacilityId,
                            intUserId
                        );

                        results.Add(printqResult);

                        if (!printqResult.WasSuccessful)
                        {
                            CloseFailedTrans(dbContext, transaction);

                            return results;
                        }

                        //Everything inserted correctly
                        CloseSuccessTrans(dbContext, transaction);

                    } //using statement
                } //if rcv qty > 0
            } // for each loop

            dbContext.Database.Connection.Dispose();

            return results;
        }
```

Here are the transaction related methods:

```
// Close DB Connections and transaction
        private void CloseFailedTrans(InventoryMgmtContext dbContext, TransactionScope transaction)
        {
            //TODO: logging
            CloseTrans(dbContext, transaction);
        }

        // Close DB Connections and transaction
        private void CloseSuccessTrans(InventoryMgmtContext dbContext, TransactionScope transaction)
        {
            transaction.Complete();
            CloseTrans(dbContext, transaction);
        }
        // Close DB Connections and transaction
        private void CloseTrans(InventoryMgmtContext dbContext, TransactionScope transaction)
        {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
```

Here is an example of one of the methods that does the insert. They all follow the same pattern:

```
//Create Receipt Header
        private ActionConfirmation<int> CreateReceiptHeader(
            InventoryMgmtContext dbContext,
            int intUserId,
            int intFacilityId
        )
        {
            //var repository = new Repository<ReceiptHeader>(dbContext);
            var repository = new ReceiptHeaderRepository(dbContext);

            //Create new Receipt Header
            ReceiptHeader rcptHdr = new ReceiptHeader()
            {
                FacilityId = intFacilityId,
                StatusId = 1,
                CreatedById = intUserId,
                CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                ModifiedById = intUserId,
                ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now
            };

            return repository.Insert(rcptHdr);
        }
```

And here is the repository insert method:

```
public virtual ActionConfirmation<int> Insert(TRepository entity)
        {
            try
            {
                _dataContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                _dataContext.SaveChanges();

                return CRUDMessage(true, "saved", entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return CRUDMessage(false, "save", entity, ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If Recp Hdr create failed how you can see record in Recp header table?

Comment: No you wouldn't. The issue is if Recpt Header succeeds, but any other subsequent one fails, Recpt Header row still exists. I.e. there are 6 db interactions, if the failure occurs on the last one, all the prior 4 rolled back but the first one, Recpt Header, does not.

Comment: It seems to me that if you create a new context where you currently start a `TransactionScope`, you don't need the latter at all. Remove the multiple exit points (`return`) and just call `SaveChanges` at the end once and catch exceptions.

Comment: So with EF, the context is the transaction in essence, so you can do all your context entry modifications like _dataContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added; and then if all are successful call SaveChanges(), if not, you call dbContext.Dispose(); and then none of the changes will be committed? I will have to modify my repository class to accept a bool to determine if to savechanges and for these, do not save changes until the very end....Sorry, thinking out loud.

Comment: That's correct. _Only_ `SaveChanges()` commits changes and it manages its own transaction. It saves all, or nothing.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks Gert! This worked perfectly. If you will add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer so you get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `TransactionScope`. Just create a new context where you currently start the `TransactionScope`. To make this work well, you need to remove the multiple exit points (`return`) and just call `SaveChanges()` at the end once and catch exceptions. That will also clean up your code and make it better maintainable (multiple exit point are considered an anti pattern).

Only `SaveChanges()`, and nothing else, commits changes to the database. `SaveChanges()` manages its own transaction: it saves all, or nothing.

Comment: @Chad Richardson :What if need to keep the context in business level and use it for multiple transactions and rollback or commit them based on user describe and keep the same context and continue using ex queries (which maybe used them as `datasource` of combos...) and use(like modify) them in the new context and save them without getting errors ? thanx.

Comment: @Mohsen It is never recommended to use a long-lived context. Use it as a unit of work.

Answer (score 1):

Since .Net 4 if all Db changes are fired off in one single call to SaveChanges() then Entity Framework decides the order they are actually executed.

It's general order of execution is DELETE, INSERT and finally UPDATE.

If the order of your inserts do not matter, e.g. no foreign key type constraints then a single SaveChanges() will work fine.

If the order of your inserts does matter, there is no way to force EF to change the order statements are executed in.

The first solution I would suggest is to make multiple calls to SaveChanges() which after each call to SaveChanges() makes the context forget about it's changes so RollBack is not possible.

The second solution I would suggest is to provide Rollback capability would be to use TransactionScope and use SaveChanges(false) (false makes the object context remember it's changes thus making rollback possible) or savechanges() with save options (the new way of doing it).

e.g.

```
var scope = new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
    // we will allow volatile data to be read during transaction
    new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }
);

using (scope)
{
  // Create new contexts for each operation
  Entities myEntities = new Entities();
  Entities myEntities2 = new Entities();

  // Do stuff with the contexts

  // Insert into myEntities then call myEntities.SaveChanges(false);
  // Insert into myEntities2 then call myEntities.SaveChanges(false);

  scope.Complete();
  myEntities.Context.AcceptAllChanges();
  myEntities2.Context.AcceptAllChanges();
}
```